# How do I dynamically add an extra TextBlock or ComboBox in the last column of a Silverlight Grid?

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml

I have a xaml as string. The content looks like this:

```
<Grid Canvas.Top="100">
 <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
  <ColumnDefinition/> 
  <ColumnDefinition/> 
  <ColumnDefinition/> 
  <ColumnDefinition/> 
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
 <RowDefinition Height="Auto" /> 
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
<TextBlock FontSize="12" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">Alfa2</TextBlock>
<TextBlock Text="?" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" />   
<TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" xml:space="preserve">15</TextBlock>     
</Grid>
```

If there is a TextBlock with `Text="?"` then i want to add an extra TextBlock or ComboBox in the last Column in the same Row. What should i use to find the `Text="?"` and how can i add new elements inside the Grid?

**EDIT** This is how i get the XAML as string

```
byte[] decryptedData = DecryptData(Result);
string xmlStr = CryptoHandler.Decompress(decryptedData, Result.Length);
```

From here i have to check the `xmlStr` for `TextBlocks` with `Text=?`. If there is such a `TextBlock` then i have to add a second `TextBlock`

Comment: Can you not just add the TextBlock in the XAML and change its Visibility from Collapsed to Visible when necessary?

Comment: I can access the XAML only through the string. In code behind i decode a file and recive the string with xaml inside.If a Grid contains `?` than on that Row i have to add a TextBlock.No chance to change the XAML directly

Comment: Can you edit the XAML at all? Like for instance to add a DataTrigger where in when Text="?" you could then toggle the visibility of an additional object (TextBlock)?

Comment: What happens with the XAML after you have changed it?

Comment: The problem is that i dont know how to change it at runtime

Comment: You're asking the wrong question.  Your question should be "How do I dynamically add an extra TextBlock or ComboBox in the last column of a Silverlight Grid?  The answer might not involve Xaml at all.  AFAIK the Xaml itself is static; you can't change it at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you don't work directly with XAML at runtime in Silverlight (or WPF). You work with the element hierarchy (equivalent of working with the DOM in HTML).

All your controls are simply children of your grid element, with specific Grid *attached properties* set on them (e.g. Grid.Row and Grid.Column).

So to clarify your various question:

- To find a control iterate the children of the grid
- To match the control content cast to the control type and check the Text property
- To add a new control Add it to the Grid's `Children`
- To set the position in the grid set the attached properties (Grid.Row & Grid.Column)

Example: Assuming you add a load event and name your grid target:

```
    <Grid x:Name="TargetGrid" Canvas.Top="100" Loaded="Grid_Loaded">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock FontSize="12" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">Alfa2</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Text="?" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" />
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" xml:space="preserve">15</TextBlock>
    </Grid>
```

Then on load (or other event) you can do something like this:

```
    private void Grid_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Index of last column
        int lastColumn = TargetGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Count - 1;

        // Iterate all child elements
        foreach (UIElement uiElement in TargetGrid.Children.ToList())
        {
            // See if the element is a Textbox
            TextBlock textBlock = uiElement as TextBlock;
            if (textBlock != null)
            {
                // if the textbox contains "?"
                if (textBlock.Text == "?")
                {
                    // Get column of textbox
                    int row = (int)textBlock.GetValue(Grid.RowProperty);

                    // Add a new control in the last column (same row)
                    var newTextBox = new TextBox();
                    newTextBox.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, row);
                    newTextBox.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, lastColumn);
                    newTextBox.Text = string.Format("I am a new Textbox in row {0}, col {1}", row, lastColumn);
                    TargetGrid.Children.Add(newTextBox);

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This will add a new control (whatever type you specify instead of TextBox) in the last column of any row that has a TextBlock containing "?":
[image]

Comment: The XAML's are saved in the database without `x:Name` for the `Grid` and without `load events`. If i read them than i get a XAML without  those properties.

Comment: @Georg: Why are you loading XAML directly at all? You can always navigate the visual tree and find element dynamically (e.g. by type), but it sounds like you are doing something "odd" by loading the raw XAML in the first place.

Comment: I have to load XAML directly, because someone else adds the XAMLs in a directory, and then i have to load them.

Comment: @Georg: Is this some kind of dynamic form creation? Can you explain why the XAML files are added to a directory for manual loading instead of being added to the project? Is your tool designed to modify the source XAML for a project, or at runtime?

Comment: '@'HiTech Magic:Yes it is dynamic. I don't know the content of the XAMLs and i have to modify at runtime.I have a FileWatcher that checks if new files are added and than should call a method to check the content of the XAML and modify if it finds TextBlocj with '?'

Comment: @Georg: Your comments imply two different things: 1) That you modify the files when they are changed and not when they are displayed and 2) but that you do it at runtime in the Silverlight app... is it `1)`, `2)` or something else (e.g. just a utility to modify the files in the folder)?

Comment: I modify the files when they are added to the folder.When i opened the topic i didn't use FIleWatcher. Now i use it to see if new files are added in the folder.If yes i check the files if they contain TextBlock with Text=?.

Comment: @Georg: To clarify: You only need to modify the text files as they are supplied and not run them at that time (but they will be used at sometime later in an app)? If so, you should consider using XML parsing instead and treat them as nothing more than XML files text (rather than XAML). You may want to clarify your original question with as much detail as possible as the aim is not clear.